# When will updates to an integer on a multi-core, multi-NUMA zone system be visible to all cores across all NUMA zones

Tags: atomic

As per title. For PPC, ARM, x86 and for writes to a non-atomic, natively-sized integer, when will the results of those writes be visible across all cores on the system?

More specifically, will a write to a memory location on one core, immediately invalidate the L1/L2 caches of other cores for that memory location, or could there be a delay where different cores have different views of the value stored at that memory location?  What is the mechanism by which the caches are invalidated?

Comment: This a problem of cache coherence, see [here] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence).